# Angular 5 can not play audio files

Tags: angular, html, html5-audio

I have got a Angular 5 project. Its getting file paths from database and play them. But some of my filenames are like '[Teknik-Servis%3A905533837273]_05533837273-630_20181005104235(160133).wav' and including special characters like :,[] % etc.. So when i play this file im getting 
**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.** error at console. %3A is ':' character so when i call url maybe browser try to change it so getting error. But there is no problem while playing this filename like '[630 Selcuk]_630-140_20180919082432(76142).wav' 
Is there any way to play this audio files that got special characters (%3A,%5B) at their filenames?

My audio play function;

```
    playAudio(filepath) {

    let filename= filepath.replace(/^.*(\\|\/|\:)/, '');
    console.log(filepath);
   if (this.audio.src.replace(/^.*(\\|\/|\:)/, '') == filename) {
  // if(this.audio.src==filepath){
      if (this.audio.paused)
        this.audio.play();
      else
        this.audio.pause();
    }
    else {
      this.audio.pause();
      this.audio = new Audio();

      this.audio.src = filepath;
      this.audio.load();
      this.audio.play();
    }

  }
```

Comment: try to use it like this: `this.audio.src = encodeURIComponent(filepath);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your file names with `encodeURIComponent()` for example.

```
this.audio.src = encodeURIComponent(filepath);
```